# Can I get the day of week from DateTime as a number?

Tags: ruby, ruby-1.8.7

If I have a `Date` object, I can get the day of the week from it as an integer, Monday = 1, Sunday = 7, like so:

```
date.cwday
```

Can I do the same thing to `DateTime` objects in Rails? I know that I can use `strftime`, but I'm doing some operations in a loop with a large data set with potentially hundreds of thousands of items, and would like to avoid extra conversions between strings and ints if possible.

Comment: Now that I look at my code some more, it looks like the reason I'm confused is because I'm getting a Time object where I expect a DateTime object. Thanks for the help!

Comment: In Rails, you can also use `to_datetime` to convert a `Time`. Not sure how this affects performance though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `DateTime` class inherits the `cwday` method from the `Date` class, so yes. I suggest visiting www.ruby-doc.org. `Date` and `DateTime` are in the standard (not core) library. Remember to choose the correct ruby version.

Also, if you're concerned about performance, there shouldn't be any performance penalty when using `DateTime#cwday` because the method is inherited from `Date` (not overridden). Note also that in ruby 1.8.7, both classes are written in pure ruby; while in 1.9, they're compiled C code (ruby-doc shows date_core.c as the source file). Your date code will likely run faster in 1.9.

Comment: Date isn't listed in the core docs, but you can create a Date object without requiring anything, so it's got to be in there somehow. The object created doesn't have any methods though so you can't do much with it.

Comment: @theTinMan `Date` isn't in core, but in standard lib. You must require date; try this from command line: `ruby -e 'p Date'`. However, `irb` seems to create an "empty" `Date` class as you say.

Comment: @theTinMan Well what do you know, it looks like an empty `Date` class is created by `lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/specification.rb`, which `irb` loads.

Comment: For the curious, the above comments apply to ruby 1.9. Further investigation shows that `irb/locale` calls `Gem.try_activate` which appears to autoload `rubygems/specification`.

Comment: I initially noticed the behavior in IRB, but confirmed it by writing a simple Ruby script that only did `puts Date.new` and ran it. No errors occurred, and I got an inspect output for a Date object. It's not useful in any way I can see without the regular Date methods, so it's just a curiosity that I'm not overly curious about.

Answer (score 4):

I think so yes

```
1.9.3-p392 :002 > DateTime.new
 => Mon, 01 Jan -4712 00:00:00 +0000
1.9.3-p392 :003 > _.cwday
 => 1
```